# Android Showing a Image From Url from GridView in FullScreen

Tags: android, gridview

I have a custom `GridView` `Adapter`, and showing some images from `MySQL` database. How can i show image in *Full Screen*?

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.paperless.custom;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dk.paperless.ProjeDuyurulari;
import com.dk.paperless.R;

public class ProjeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public ProjeAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }          

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }       

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.projeduyurugrid, null);

        TextView projeIsim= (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.projeIsim); // proje ismi
        ImageView projeResim = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.projeResim); // proje resmi


        HashMap<String, String> proje = new HashMap<String, String>();
        proje = data.get(position);


        projeIsim.setText(proje.get(ProjeDuyurulari.TAG_PROJEADI));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(proje.get(ProjeDuyurulari.TAG_FOTOGRAF), projeResim);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

And i set it to GridView :

```
adapter=new ProjeAdapter(ProjeDuyurulari.this, projeList); 
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

OnClick Method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //tried some stuff here like getId()... getId() gives -1 all time time btw.
}
```

I put the URl in String like this:

```
String fotograf = c.getString(TAG_FOTOGRAF);
```

projeduyurugrid:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/projeResim"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/projeresmi"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/projeIsim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/projeResim"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/projeismi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can pass position to your new Activity after click on GridView.

Comment: Share your layout projeduyurugrid

Comment: I created an Activity named FullScreen.class, i just couldn't figure out how can i pass the URL. Can you show me a quick example?

@Brontok i added.

Comment: Do you want something like when you click on any image , It gets displayed in full screen? right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose getting the *index* of clicked item will be enough

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //tried some stuff here like getId()... getId() gives -1 all time time btw.
}
```

**arg2** is the index of clicked item use it to get the *URL* as : `d.get(arg2).get(ProjeDuyurulari.TAG_FOTOGRAF)` and pass it to your new `Activity` where you want to display the image full screen

Hope it helps dostum (:

Comment: I started Andorid Development nearly a month or two. I took the first part from a ListView tutorial. I knew its probably wrong. Teşekkürler for help :)

Comment: @user666 keep the first part, i was wrong about it and updated my answer. Somehow my eyes totally ignored the line `proje = data.get(position);` which was correct.

Answer (score 1):

First Make your ***ArrayList*** ***static*** in which your Image URL saved.

After that use this:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
          Intent n = new Intent(SourceActivity.this,yourDesiredActivity.this);
          n.putExtra("postition",arg2);  
          startActivity(n);  
    }
  });
```

Now in your Desired Activity retrieve

```
 Intent n = getIntent();

 int pos = n.getIntExtras("position",0);

 urImageview.setImageResource(yourActivity.arraylist[pos]);
```

Comment: What about this:
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>